# Windows 10 USB keyboard and USB mouse became totally dead

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, hard-drive-recovery

Out of the blue my mouse and usb keyboard stopped working completely (without any reboots). Feels like PC is dead, keyboard doesn't respond to num-lock or caps-lock, lights do not change at all. I tried to reboot: no way to fix, mouse and keyboard are listed in device manager as unknown devices that do not have drivers. Any clues what could be wrong, how to fix it?

**Update:**

While trying to do system restore to attempt to erpair the issue, my PC went into endless reboot loop where I cannot even start it now, not even safe mode. Fail code is: 0xc000021a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appears the problem is Microsoft's fault and is related to [KB4074588](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4091240/usb-devices-may-stop-working-after-installing-the-february-13-2018-upd). Somehow they ended up pushing update that could remove USB drivers and would fail to install new ones.

I've had that problem a few times, today it happened once again and I tried to figure out what's going on. Randomly usb mouse and usb keyboard drivers would magically evaporate without doing any updates or restarts, in the middle of typing keyboard and mouse would suddenly "disappear". I tried to do system restore, this totally corrupted my system and I wasn't able to boot anymore (not even in safe mode). BSOD error code was `0xc000021a` which is [Bug Check 0xC000021A: STATUS_SYSTEM_PROCESS_TERMINATED](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/bug-check-0xc000021a--status-system-process-terminated). At this point google suggested to "[Disable Driver Signature Enforcement](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/t/643879/windows-reboot-loop-disable-driver-signature-enforcement-is-the-only-way/)" in advanced option, this helped to boot and restore evaporated drivers. However, they would again evaporate after a few hours of use. I tried to contact Microsoft, but got random copy-pasta recipe to check that connectors were ok or something like that.

Some googling and I found a [large thread discussing this same issue](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/t/671179/recent-windows-10-update-breaks-usb-mouse-and-keyboard-on-dell-3040/) on bleepingcomputer.com. In short, the solution is to uninstall KB4074588, suggested way by Microsoft, from admin cmd prompt:

For 32-bit versions of Windows:

```
dism /online /remove-package /packagename:Package_for_RollupFix~31bf3856ad364e35~x86~~16299.248.1.17
```

For 64-bit versions of Windows:

```
dism /online /remove-package /packagename:Package_for_RollupFix~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~16299.248.1.17
```

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me too with the storage USB drivers when I prevented Windows from automatically updating.

You need to let widows itself update the specific USB device drivers that are no longer working because it's very likely that it will not let you use anything else, even official manufacturer drivers.

Use a PS/2 adapter or Keyboard and go to Device Manager and force-update the drivers via windows update system.

Comment: tried update, doesn't work. I didn't touch updates, didn't do anything at all, keyboard simply became dead and stopped working while I was typing.

Comment: most importantly, I had that same issue a month ago, and a week ago.

Answer (score 1):

The 0xC000021A error is a Blue Screen of Death or BSoD error (related: Blue Screen of Death guide) that occurs when a Windows user-mode subsystem is compromised.

Please try following repairs:

Start the system to the installation media for the installed version of Windows.

Note For more information, see Create installation media for Windows.
On the Install Windows screen, select Next > Repair your computer.
On the System Recovery Options screen, select Next > Command Prompt.
At the command prompt, run the following command by using BCDEdit command-line options to identify the drive letter of the system volume:

BCDEdit

In the Windows Boot Loader section, the drive letter of the system volume is displayed next to "osdevice." (For example, D:)
At the command prompt, run the following command to complete a check disk for the system volume that's identified in step 4:

**CHKDSK /f D:**

Note If any failures or unrepairable issues are listed in the results, you may have to investigate these further.

At the command prompt, run the following command to complete a System File Check (SFC) for the system volume that's identified in step 4:

**SFC /scannow /offbootdir=D:\ /offwindir=D:\windows**

Note If any failures or unrepairable issues are listed in the results, you may have to investigate these further.

At the command prompt, run the following command to complete an image cleanup and health restoration by using the DISM tool:

**DISM /image:D:\ /cleanup-image /restorehealth**

Comment: see my own answer, the problem is already solved